# Graph API /me/joinedTeams unexpected result

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm having some issues with the [List joinedTeams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-joinedteams?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph api endpoint.

I was expecting that `me/joinedTeams` would give the same result as `users/my-user-id/joinedTeams`, however the first one only returns one team and the second returns multiple (haven't checked if it's complete).

So the question is, did I find a bug in the Graph API or is there something else going on?

- I'm using delegated permissions
- I've checked the token at [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms), the **aud** is `00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000` and it includes the following scopes:

  - `Directory.Read.All`
  - `Group.Read.All`
  - `Member.Read.Hidden`
  - `Team.ReadBasic.All`
  - `User.Read`

**Update**: It seems I can no longer reproduce the issue, so I'm concluding that there was some short issue with syncing between the Azure AD and the responding Graph API server.

Comment: just a silly question (the only possibility i can think of) how sure you are typing the correct user id?

Comment: I copied it from https://aad.portal.azure.com and after that I loaded the UserId from the user session (openid connect).

Comment: I just tested these two APIs with https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer and they did return the same result to me.

Answer (score -1):

My idea is the same as @Ergec, you need to make sure you are using the same user id.

I just tested these two APIs with [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and they did return the same result to me.

I suggest you first request the `/me` endpoint to get the id, then paste it to the `/users` endpoint, making sure they use the same id.

1.
[image]

2.
[image]

Comment: Telling me how to copy an ID doesn't really help in solving the issue. I will add screenshots proving the issue.